# Change texture Image via script

Tags: python, texturing, scripting

I have a 3d Object and want to save it with multiple texture images.

I've unwrapped the object and in the shading-editor I imported multiple pictures.

With the UV-editor I've scaled my picture.
With Shift+F I can swap between the Images in the shading editor.

This is how it looks:

[image: this is how it looks]

I'm totally new to scripting with blender. Is there a way to do the steps above with an script, or with python

Comment: Hi. As I understand you need to bake bunch of textures as maps for the object - right?

Comment: Maybe you could consider the set of images as an image-sequence, and automate the offset within the sequence (maybe not needing a script). What is your final _use_ for the multiple images?